# dividing function into screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code which affects my navigation

```js
let opened = false; // set the nav as closed by default
function toggleNav() {
  if (!opened) { // if opened is false (ie nav is closed), open the nav
    openNav()
  } else { // else, if opened is true (ie nav is open), close the nav
    closeNav();
  }
  opened = !opened; // negate boolean to get opposite (t to f, and f to t)
}

function openNav() {
  $('#myTopnav').addClass('openHeight').removeClass('closeHeight');
  $('#main').addClass('openMain').removeClass('closeMain');
}

function closeNav() {
  $('#myTopnav').removeClass('openHeight').addClass('closeHeight');
  $('#main').removeClass('openMain').addClass('closeMain');
}
```

I want the openNav and closeNav function to affect screen sizes smaller than 720px, I want to have a different openNav and closeNav function for screen sizes larger. I'm not sure how to apply the if and else statement to achieve this.

EDIT: I apologize, this is a Wordpress site, so I wasn't sure if php would be part of a suggested solution

Comment: How is this a question about PHP?

Comment: What is the structure of your HTML? What are you expecting to happen that is not happening?

Comment: I would use the same functionality to affect the same classNames based on `@media screen and (max-width: 720px){ /* small screen CSS override here */ }`, which would be the CSS for small screens to override CSS which comes before the `@media`.

Comment: You're trying to solve a CSS problem by throwing at it some JS. Good news: there is already a CSS solution to that very CSS problem. It's called `media queries`. 
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: the reason I can't just use media queries is because I need to add and remove classes/styles at different screen sizes  based on clicks, mouse locations, etc. Navigation can open and close multiple times on multiple screen sizes. The media queries need to be included in the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Window resize function as:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(this).width() >= 1280) {
     //Your Code Here
  }
});
```

The above function will work when your window size is  `>=`  1200

In Your Scenario it will be like:

```
  //For Example You want to toggle your nav here
  if ($(window).width() > 720) {
     toggleNav2(); //Which you have created for less than 720px screen
  }else{
     toggleNav1(); //Which you have created for larger than 720px screen
  }
```

Comment: can I just wrap each openNav/closeNav  in this or is there a way to wrap them both in one?